# Easiest way to remove Latex tag (but not its content)?

Tags: latex, tags

I am using TeXnicCenter to edit a LaTeX document.

I now want to remove a certain tag (say, `emph{blabla}`} which occurs multiple times in my document , but not tag's content (so in this example, I want to remove all emphasization).
What is the easiest way to do so?

May also be using another program easily available on Windows 7.

**Edit:** In response to regex suggestions, it is important that it can deal with nested tags.

**Edit 2:** I really want to remove the tag from the text file, not just disable it.

Comment: I'm going to assume you mean \emph{blabla} if you don't for some reason you may remove the \\ from my regex in my answer

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you find a way to do this, especially on nested tags, and truly remove them? I've been searching online for hours and nothing. Some answers just handle specific cases

Answer (score 4):

Using a regular expression do something like `s/\\emph\{([^\}]*)\}/\1/g`. If you are not familiar with regular expressions this says:

```
s -- replace
/ -- begin match section
\\emph\{ -- match \emph{
( -- begin capture
[^\}]* -- match any characters except (meaning up until) a close brace because:
  [] a group of characters
  ^ means not or "everything except"
  \} -- the close brace
  and * means 0 or more times
) -- end capture, because this is the first (in this case only) capture, it is number 1
\} -- match end brace
/ -- begin replace section
\1 -- replace with captured section number 1
/ -- end regular expression, begin extra flags
g -- global flag, meaning do this every time the match is found not just the first time
```

This is with Perl syntax, as that is what I am familiar with. The following perl "one-liners" will accomplish two tasks

`perl -pe 's/\\emph\{([^\}]*)\}/\1/g' filename` will "test" printing the file to the command line

`perl -pi -e 's/\\emph\{([^\}]*)\}/\1/g' filename` will change the file in place.

Similar commands may be available in your editor, but if not this will (should) work.

Comment: Thanks, if one is going to answer one may as well do it with gusto

Comment: Will it function correctly if there is another tag inside the tag to remove (i.e, meaning there will be a closing brace before encoutering the correct closing brace)?

Comment: @Raberberski: No. Matching parenthesis with regexps is known to be quite a hard problem.

Comment: As Heinzi said, it is more difficult in that case. Here is a link with some discussion http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=660316 . They are considering angle brackets but replacing with curly should be no problem. They recursively parse out each nested text.

Comment: Perhaps something better for you is the Perl module (as suggested in that link) is the Text::Balanced module http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Text-Balanced-2.02/lib/Text/Balanced.pm .

Comment: Just want to add that for regex replacement in Overleaf, this would be:
Find: \\emph\{([^\}]*)\}
Replace: $1

Answer (score 1):

Crowley should have added this as an answer, but I will do that for him, if you replace all \emph{ with { you should be able to do this without disturbing the other content. It will still be in braces, but unless you have done some odd stuff it shouldn't matter.

The regex would be a simple `s/\\emph\{/\{/g` but the search and replace in your editor will do that one too.

Edit: Sorry, used the wrong brace in the regex, fixed now.

Comment: nice workaround ! (I failed to grasp Crowley's answer at the time)

Answer (score 1):

`\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{#1}`

Answer (score 0):

any reasonably advanced editor should let you do a search/replace using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), replacing `emph{bla}` by `bla` etc.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to say: "replace `\emph{` with `{`"?